# Why ubuntu is not detecting my AMD Radeon graphics?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop HP Pavilion dv6 6121se
Specs:
intel core i7 2670QM 2.2 GHz
AMD Radeon 6490M 512 MB
Intel HD 3000 512 MB
4 GB RAM
500 GB HDD
Dual boot between Windows 7 and this ubuntu.
In 'about system'
Graphics:Intel sandybridge Mobile
then why not AMD Radeon
I want my GFX fully recoginzed 
What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the graphic driver for your AMD graphic card. For this:-

1. Note that you must install your graphic driver only after completely updating your OS. Therefore you must first Updte your OS.
2. Then, go to [this site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) . You can find the right driver for your graphic card there by specifying the right options in the list boxes in the site. If you cant find the right driver, then you can install that auto detect software found in the same site in your Windows OS, know your graphic card details  and then come back to Ubuntu and get the right driver.
3. Next most importantly **check out the the release notes of the driver you are going to install.** Check if your **OS meets all the system requirements of the driver as specified in the release notes**.
4. Then **follow the installer notes** to successfully install your driver.

If you run into problems(ie if unity desktop doesnt open or if you have a similar problem) after installing the driver it might mean that you have installed an unsupported driver. So start a tty session by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 . There type the following:

```
sudo aticonfig --uninstall
```

This should delete the driver you installed. Then type:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This should reboot your computer and now Unity would open so that you can now follow the process all over again to find the right driver and install it.

Comment: In the link to the AMD site mentioned above, select Linux x86 for 32-bit OS and Linux x86_64 for 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

you can download ati/amd proprietary fglrx graphics driver, but be careful with installation, you'r system may become crashed, here is download link http://support.amd.com/en-us/download (at right you will see linux (32&64)), but please read users reviews about installation and compatibility at ubuntu forums :) hope it was helpful